# Swift/iOS: Generics Error: protocol requires nested type 'V'; do you want to add it?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-playground

I am using Playground, Swift version 5.7.1.

I have two protocols, and two classes. This first one is simple and it works:

```
protocol TestSomeB: ObservableObject {
   associatedtype V: View
   func returnSome() -> V
}

class TestSomeBImp: TestSomeB {
   init() {}

   func returnSome() -> some View {
      Text("Hello World")
   }
}

let testSomeBImp = TestSomeBImp()
testSomeBImp.returnSome()
```

This works and gives me the value `{{SwiftUI.AnyTextStorage, {key "Hello World", hasFormatting false, []}, nil, nil}}`

The second one doesn't work even though the basic code structure is the same:

```
struct TestModel {
   var title: String
}

struct TestView: View {
   var body: some View {
       Text("Hello, World!")
   }
}

// similar to protocol TestSomeB
protocol TestSomeA: ObservableObject {
    associatedtype V: View
    func linkBuilder<Content: View>(data: TestModel, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> V
}

class TestSomeAImp: TestSomeA {
   init() {}

   // returns `some View` similar to returnSome() method above
   func linkBuilder<Content: View>(data: TestModel, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
      NavigationLink(destination: routeToPage(data: data)) {
         content()
      }
   }

   private func routeToPage(data: TestModel) -> some View {
       TestView()
   }
}

let testSomeImp = TestSomeAImp()
testSomeImp.linkBuilder(
    data: TestModel(title: "Hello "),
    content: {
       Text("World!")
    }
)
```

Sadly this gives me the error: `protocol requires nested type 'V'; do you want to add it? associatedtype V: View`

- I need to return `some View` but I also need to abstract my implementation.
- I tried using `Content` instead of `V` in the return type but that gives me error too.
- I tried using only `associatedtype V` in the protocol without specifying the type, but that also gives me an error.
- I tried creating two associated types, one V, and the other for Content, but that actually gave me the same `nested` error
- I tried adding the `typealias V`, but since it's nested, the error keeps occurring again and again.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your protocol requirement is that you offer this:

```
func linkBuilder<Content: View>(data: TestModel, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> V
```

Given a `Content`, you promise to always return a value of type `V`, which is determined by the implementation of the protocol. There is precisely one type `V` for a given implementation type.

You then you implement it as:

```
func linkBuilder<Content: View>(data: TestModel, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
```

This says that `linkBuilder` will return an opaque type that depends on `Content`, which is determined by the *caller*. Each call to `linkBuilder` can return a different specific type, depending on what `Content` is. This does not match "will always return `V`, which is a specific, concrete type defined at compile time for this implementation."

In your first example, the type returned is exactly `Text`. In your failing example, your type depends on `Content`.

Try getting rid of all of the `some` types, and it will be more clear what's going on. (A `some` type must always be replaceable with a known-at-compiletime, type. It's opaque; it's not dynamic.)

```
func linkBuilder<Content: View>(data: TestModel, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
    -> NavigationLink<Content, TestView> {
    NavigationLink(destination: routeToPage(data: data), label: content)
}

private func routeToPage(data: TestModel) -> TestView {
    TestView()
}
```

So you could make a protocol for that certainly, though I expect this isn't what you want:

```
protocol TestSomeA: ObservableObject {
    func linkBuilder<Content: View>(data: TestModel, 
                                    @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) 
        -> NavigationLink<Content, TestView>
}
```

Another important thing to understand here is that `NavigationLink<Text, TestView>` is a completely different type than `NavigationLink<Image, TestViw>`. There is no way to directly express "a NavigationLink with arbitrary parameters."

It's not clear here what the point of the protocol is here. It's not clear what another implementation of `TestSomeA` would look like, and how callers would use it without knowing the types. Your `linkBuilder` is fine; it's just the throwing in a protocol that makes it messy. What problem is this solving?

Comment: I have a method `func linkBuilder<Content: View>(data: TestModel, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: routeToPage(data: data), label: content)
}` that I want to abstract so I'm writing a protocol so other classes/structs can conform to it. Ultimately, it will be nice to have a NavigationLink to be able to navigate from anywhere to anywhere. But based on your response `There is no way to directly express "a NavigationLink with arbitrary parameters."` , it looks like there is no way for that to happen.